# dataset not returning doing select oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, string-constant

I have a data in oracle db DJSHJSJD-DJDJJJDK-D'FJDJSS when i tried to do a filter it is throwing error

```
select * from test
where dummy='DJSHJSJD-DJDJJJDK-D'FJDJSS' ;

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where dummy='DJSHJSJD-DJDJJJDK-D''FJDJSS' ;
```

I.e. double the quote character inside the string literal.

Comment: excellent for the quick response - short explanation ?

Comment: The SQL scanner otherwise thinks the string is `'DJSHJSJD-DJDJJJDK-D'` only, followed by `FJDJSS' ;`, where FJDJSS makes no sense.